# Django doesn't extends to base.html in parent folder

Tags: python, django, templates, django-templates, extends

I'm in `myapp/templates/registration.login.html`. My login.html templates starts with `{% extends "base.html"%}`, "base.html" is in the folder templates.

Now, as result, my login.html page is blank. If I remobe the *extends* line it works. I added in settings: `TEMPLATE_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/templates/')]` but base.html is still a ghost for login.html.

There's something I can't see. What could be the problem? I tried also to change the TEMPLATES_DIRS with `TEMPLATE_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]` and every slash combination. It doesn't work.

Any idea? Thank you.

This is the app tree (not all of it:

```
project
-\templates
--base.html
--home.html
--\registration
---login.html
```

In \registration\login.html the `extends` doesn't work, while it does in home.html.

Comment: Please add your `settings.py` to your question, and your directory layout. Also, clarify exactly where is `base.html`, is it in `/app/templates/` or some other 'templates' directory?

Comment: Are you using the same `block` names you defined in your `base.html` in your `registration.login.html`? I had problems before where I didn't use the correct `block` names and the page rendered blank, as the original `block`s defined in my base template were not overridden.

Comment: You got it Bruno! :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem was not in the path, but in the block names. I had `{% block content %}` instead of `{% block name %}`

Comment: This did not work for me. Did you just change `{% block content %}` to `{% block name %}`? Or any other changes? I have the exact same structure as you.

Comment: I figured that I had to wrap the body of my login.html page in the `{% block content %} ... {% endblock%}` tags. This was not shown in the tutorial I was following, so I got confused.